# How to clone Windows 7 into a image file?

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtual-machine, xen

I want to clone my Windows 7 system into a image file and boot it from my Xen vm. Windows 7 has a boot partition and a system partition. I know there are plenty of tools in Linux that can clone a partition into a image file. But I have no idea how to clone two partitions into **one** image file, and also keep the partition meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sysinternals disk2vhd can write a single VHD file with multiple partitions on it (including the System Reserved Partition).  The resulting VHD will mount in Windows 7 as multiple partitions.

As for whether it'll boot up in Xen right away, you'd have to try it and see.  There are other issues involved there, like drivers and such.

Comment: thanks a lot. I think after the partitions are converted, the most pressing issue would be the boot loader.